# Effective Use of Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to use single fragment twice in landscape mode and once in portrait mode.

The xml for landscape mode:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <fragment class="com.afghanmag.android.StoreViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/categories" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <fragment class="com.afghanmag.android.StoreViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/library" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

How can I design the portrait mode view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <fragment class="com.afghanmag.android.StoreViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```